# Mark specific frequencies in smithchart

Tags: matlab, smith-chart

I have a smithchart created by MATLAB using the following code (the S22 is a 801x1 vector obtained from a file):

n = 801;
fStart = 45*10^6;
fStop = 15*10^9;
f = linspace(fStart,fStop,n);
figure()
smithchart(S22)
title('S22 with 50 $\Omega$ SMD resistor','interpreter','latex')

Is it possible to mark specific frequencies as dots in the diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy workaround to plot corresponding frequencies from S-parameter vector:

hold on
plot(S22(1), 'r*')
plot(S22(159),'r*')
plot(S22(end),'r*')

The result looks like this:

[image]